# Error in java console program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("System.in");
        System.out.println("Yntreq (1/2):");
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        switch (y) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Duq yntrel eq 1-y");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Duq yntrel eq 2-y");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

And when it runing,eclipse show this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Example.main(Example.java:7)
```

Comment: Use `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.in` is not a String!

Change:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("System.in");
```

to:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove double quote" " from "System.in"

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
instead of
Scanner sc = new Scanner("System.in");
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `""` from `Scanner sc = new Scanner("System.in");`
i.e

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have passed invalid parameter in constructor,
constructor syntax for input stream is -

```
public Scanner(InputStream source)
```

Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.
Parameters:
`source` - An input stream to be scanned

example : `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`